# Are there cognitive models that distinguish semantic and episodic memory?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, reference-request, cognitive-modeling, theoretical-neuroscience

From various amnesia cases it has been shown that semantic and episodic memories reside in different parts of the brain. Are there any cognitive models that distinguish these two types of memories? If so, how do they go about doing it?

Comment: What do you mean by a cognitive model?

Comment: As in a model that describes, either computationally or as a vaguely defined system (researches seem to like block diagrams), how these memories are differentiated.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Was wondering if you were going for any model or a whole cognitive architecture.